# Converting 8 digit number to DateTime Type

Tags: c#

I want to convert 8 digit value to a DateTime object.  How can I do this?  For example, if a user enters 08082010 then it should convert it to 08/08/2010, using C#.

Comment: What I like most about this question is the use of 8th August, which masks the fact that it is ambiguous whether we mean MM/dd/yyyy versus dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateString = "08082010";
string format = "MMddyyyy";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 6):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact()` with a format specifier of `"ddMMyyyy"` or `"MMddyyyy"`.

Answer (score 6):

I was just trying to do the same thing, and I'd have to agree with Ignacio's approach.  The answer that was accepted works but the `ParseExact` method throws an exception in the event that the date string is invalid,   while the `TryParseExact` method will just return `false`.  Example:

```
using System.Globalization;
// ...
string dateString = "12212010";
string format = "MMddyyyy";
DateTime dateStarted;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateStarted))
    dateStarted = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx)

Comment: I have tried all the methods like Parse and TryParse of DateTime but it didn't work for me that is why I hav ask the question here.

Comment: This will not work, because "08082010" is not an acceptable date format for DateTime.Parse.  Use **DateTime.ParseExact** _or_ **DateTime.TryParseExact** (depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Full fubar is

```
 private static DateTime FormatDateTimeString(string stringToFormat)
    {
        var yearStr = stringToFormat.Substring(0,4);
        var monthofyearStr = stringToFormat.Substring(4, 2);
        var dayofmonthStr = stringToFormat.Substring(6, 2);
        var hourStr = stringToFormat.Substring(8, 2);
        var minuteStr = stringToFormat.Substring(10, 2);

        var year = int.Parse(yearStr);
        var monthofyear = int.Parse(monthofyearStr);
        var dayofmonth = int.Parse(dayofmonthStr);
        var hour = int.Parse(hourStr);
        var minute = int.Parse(minuteStr);

        if (year > 999 && year < 3000)
            if(monthofyear > 0 && monthofyear< 13)
                if (dayofmonth > 0 && dayofmonth < 32)
                    if (hour >= 0 && hour < 24)
                        if (minute >= 0 && minute < 60)
                            return new DateTime(year, monthofyear, dayofmonth, hour, minute, 0);

        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
```

You can modify this to handle different string lengths for 14, 12, 8 chars and so on. Verify input before calling it.